# How can I reorganize data in SAS

Tags: sas

Data I have
list 1

1. List item

---

1. [List item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cne8z.png)

datadate    1   2   3
19890103    -0.8    0.57    -1.68
19890104    3.11    1.14    0.34
19890105    0.53    -0.28   -0.64
19890106    0.51    1.13    0.7
19890109    -0.64   -0.14   -0.06

Data I need
datadate    return  group
19890103    -0.8    1
19890104    3.11    1
19890105    0.53    1
19890106    0.51    1
19890109    -0.64   1
19890103    0.57    2
19890104    1.14    2
19890105    -0.28   2
19890106    1.13    2
19890109    -0.14   2
19890103    -1.68   3
19890104    0.34    3
19890105    -0.64   3
19890106    0.7 3
19890109    -0.06   3

Comment: Is all your data on one line? If so modify your input statement to include a trailing @@ to read the data. This question will be marked as duplicate.

Comment: datadate           1      2           3
19890103 -0.8     0.57  -1.68
19890104 3.11     1.14    0.34
19890105 0.53   -0.28 -0.64
19890106 0.51    1.13  0.7
19890109 -0.64   -0.14 -0.06
19890110 -0.48   -0.15 -0.77

Comment: I tried to add a picture because the 'data I have' data is not formatted as I tried to type it in.

Comment: the 'data I have' set looks like four columns.  Column 1 had heading 'datadate'.  The other three columns have heading 1, 2, and 3.  The body of the table contains info like -0.8 (at the intersection of 19890103 and 1); 0.57 (at the intersection of 19890103 and 2); and so on.

Comment: This is a standard proc transpose

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/widetolong_data.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-create the dataset you have:

```
data have;
    input datadate _1 _2 _3;
    datalines;
    19890103 -0.8 0.57 -1.68
    19890104 3.11 1.14 0.34
    19890105 0.53 -0.28 -0.64
    19890106 0.51 1.13 0.7
    19890109 -0.64 -0.14 -0.06
run;
```

Transpose the data:

```
proc transpose data=have out=need;
    by datadate;
    var _1 _2 _3;
run;
```

Apply some cosmetics:

```
data need2;
    set need;
    group = input(tranwrd(_name_,'_',''), 8.);
    rename col1 = return;
    label col1='Return' group = 'Group';
    drop _name_;
run;
```

Sort the data to match want you need:

```
proc sort data=need2;
    by group datadate;
run;
```